# block internt access for eth0, but allow for wlan0

Tags: iptables, raspberry-pi

Beginner here. I have the following setup. Raspberry OS on my pi. Connected to the eth0 are a bunch of network cameras.

The eth0 should act as a dhcp, so that every camera gets an IP-address. But they should not have any connection to the internet (ET not phoning home).

wlan0 should be able to access the internet.

If I understood correctly, the dhcp is out of the box. No need to change anything there. So I tried to block the internet access with iptables for eth0 and allow just the ip range of my local network.
I thought about using iptables, but not sure if it gets me, where I want.

I tried:

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.178.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

PS:192.168.178.0/24 is the local network of my router, connected to the internet.

Seems not to work. Any thoughts on how to solve my problems (with or without iptables)

Thanks so much.

Comment: You need to set up a DHCP server, that will answer the cameras DCHP requests on eth0. DHCP clients are usually "out of the box", not the server. Then, if you don't set up forwarding, you should be pretty much all set.

Answer (score 0):

You just need an OUTPUT and FORWARD rule to block internet access. Delete all existing rules and re-add:

```
$ sudo iptables -F
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.178.0/24 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.178.0/24 ! -d 192.168.178.0/24 -j DROP
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.178.0/24 ! -d 192.168.178.0/24 -j DROP
```

If it works fine, consider saving the iptables rules